# How do I update or clear the files listed in the Storage Access Framework?

Tags: storage

Some Android applications use the SAF for a 'file picker'. As I understand it, this file picker, provided by Android, has its own special set of labels under which it chooses to display files along side the traditional storage file structure.

For example, opening up the side menu gets you a list that says:
Recent, Drive, Images, Video, Audio, Downloads

Its not totally clear where the files listed under each label are pulled from. The files listed are a *history* and thus often no longer exist. So I can click on Downloads and select *FileThatNoLongerExists.txt*. This will probably result in an application error.

I want to be able to:

- Update the set of files listed through the SAF. Listing deleted files is stupid
- Clear out files I do not want to be visible through the SAF. Most computer interfaces that have a "Recent Documents" list let you clear or disable it

How would I go about doing these things?

Comment: Good observation +1.  I couldn't find any way to *refresh SAF* but you may like to give [local storage](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ianhanniballake.localstorage) a try. I deleted files from downloads, screenshots and it showed current status correctly, besides linked up my drive !

Comment: @Pris, did you find any solution to that? I am amazed that there is so little results in google about this issue. Maybe it is wrong only on my Samsung S5...